# How Deploy Metabase on App Engine with VPC Connector?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metabase

im getting stuck when try to deploy metabase on app engine with vpc connector

```
service: metabase-dwh
runtime: custom
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 8
  disk_size_gb: 25

env_variables:
  MB_DB_TYPE: mysql
  MB_DB_DBNAME: metabase_dwh
  MB_DB_USER: xxx
  MB_DB_PASS: xxx
  MB_DB_HOST: 34.101.xxx.000

vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/xxx/locations/xxx/connectors/myconnectorname
  egress_setting: all-traffic

beta_settings:
 cloud_sql_instances: xxx:xxx:metabase-sql
```

And i don't know why, why my service not attached with my vpc connector. Please help, thank you.

Comment: When using GAE Flex you don't need a connector. GAE Flex instances are already in the VPC so not sure what would the usage here. It's not clear what are you trying to do with the connector actually. Please add more details.

Comment: @Puteri how i know my service under my vpc, and which vpc is. I have vpc more than one?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation about VPCs, App Engine and the things you're trying to do before doing things and understanding them. Do you have more than 1 VPC? I don't know, that depends on your configurations but normally you'll have one. GAE Flex by default should be in the default VPC and you can test it connecting to a VM for example.